# Где ошибка в скрипте?

Tags: javascript

Найдите ошибку, помогите человеку :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var a = new Array(5, 0, 2, 0, -3, 0);
var b = new Array();
while (true) {
    var x = prompt("chislo", "0");
    x = +x;
    if (x == 0) {
        break
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] == 0) {
            b[i] = "-";
            continue;
        }
        b[i] = x / a[i];
    }
    alert(a + " \n "
    x + " \n " + b);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
alert(a+"\n"x+"\n"+b);
// а надо
alert(a+"\n"+x+"\n"+b);
// и все равно алертать массивы - это странно.
```

Answer (score 1):

Что это за магия чисел?

```
x = +x;
```

Если надо убрать знак:

```
1. x = Math.abs(x)
2. x = ( x > 0 ) ? x : -x;
3. if ( x < 0 ) x = -x;
```

Если прибавить 1, то:

```
1. x++;
2. x += 1;
3. x = x + 1;
```

Comment: Это вариация parseFloat.